# AWS Lambda based serverless Express app returns 500 internal server error

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, aws-lambda, serverless

I'm trying to create a AWS Lambda and ExpressJS based serverless app. However when I test the generated API url using postman it returns `500 "Internal server error"`.

I'm following this [guide](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/going-serverless-migrating-an-express-application-to-amazon-api-gateway-and-aws-lambda/).

**simple-proxy-api.yaml**

```
---
swagger: 2.0
info:
  title: AwsServerlessExpressApi
basePath: /prod
schemes:
- https
paths:
  /:
    x-amazon-apigateway-any-method:
      produces:
      - application/json
      responses:
        200:
          description: 200 response
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/Empty"
      x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
        responses:
          default:
            statusCode: 200
        uri: arn:aws:apigateway:us-east-1:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:101010101010:function:${stageVariables.ServerlessExpressLambdaFunctionName}/invocations
        passthroughBehavior: when_no_match
        httpMethod: POST
        type: aws_proxy
    options:
      consumes:
      - application/json
      produces:
      - application/json
      responses:
        200:
          description: 200 response
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/Empty"
          headers:
            Access-Control-Allow-Origin:
              type: string
            Access-Control-Allow-Methods:
              type: string
            Access-Control-Allow-Headers:
              type: string
      x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
        responses:
          default:
            statusCode: 200
            responseParameters:
              method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "'DELETE,GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,PATCH,POST,PUT'"
              method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "'Content-Type,Authorization,X-Amz-Date,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token'"
              method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "'https://example.com'"
        passthroughBehavior: when_no_match
        requestTemplates:
          application/json: "{\"statusCode\": 200}"
        type: mock
    get:
      summary: "Arrived at the root of the API"
      description: "Root API reached. This is for testing."
      produces:
      - application/json
      responses:
        200:
          description: 200 response
          schema:
            type: string
          headers:
            Access-Control-Allow-Origin:
              type: string
            Access-Control-Allow-Methods:
              type: string
            Access-Control-Allow-Headers:
              type: string
      x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
        responses:
          default:
            statusCode: 200
            responseParameters:
              method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "'DELETE,GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,PATCH,POST,PUT'"
              method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "'Content-Type,Authorization,X-Amz-Date,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token'"
              method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "'https://example.com'"
        passthroughBehavior: when_no_match
        requestTemplates:
          application/json: "{\"statusCode\": 200}"
        type: mock
  /friends:
    get:
      summary: "List friends"
      description: "See list of friends here"
      produces:
      - application/json
      responses:
        200:
          description: 200 response
          schema:
            type: array
            items:
              type: object
          headers:
            Access-Control-Allow-Origin:
              type: string
            Access-Control-Allow-Methods:
              type: string
            Access-Control-Allow-Headers:
              type: string
      x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
        responses:
          default:
            statusCode: 200
            responseParameters:
              method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "'DELETE,GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,PATCH,POST,PUT'"
              method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "'Content-Type,Authorization,X-Amz-Date,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token'"
              method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "'https://example.com'"
        passthroughBehavior: when_no_match
        requestTemplates:
          application/json: "{\"statusCode\": 200}"
        type: mock
    options:
      consumes:
      - application/json
      produces:
      - application/json
      responses:
        200:
          description: 200 response
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/Empty"
          headers:
            Access-Control-Allow-Origin:
              type: string
            Access-Control-Allow-Methods:
              type: string
            Access-Control-Allow-Headers:
              type: string
      x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
        responses:
          default:
            statusCode: 200
            responseParameters:
              method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "'DELETE,GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,PATCH,POST,PUT'"
              method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "'Content-Type,Authorization,X-Amz-Date,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token'"
              method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "'https://example.com'"
        passthroughBehavior: when_no_match
        requestTemplates:
          application/json: "{\"statusCode\": 200}"
        type: mock
  /{proxy+}:
    x-amazon-apigateway-any-method:
      produces:
      - application/json
      parameters:
      - name: proxy
        in: path
        required: true
        type: string
      responses: {}
      x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
        uri: arn:aws:apigateway:us-east-1:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:101010101010:function:${stageVariables.ServerlessExpressLambdaFunctionName}/invocations
        httpMethod: POST
        type: aws_proxy
    options:
      consumes:
      - application/json
      produces:
      - application/json
      responses:
        200:
          description: 200 response
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/Empty"
          headers:
            Access-Control-Allow-Origin:
              type: string
            Access-Control-Allow-Methods:
              type: string
            Access-Control-Allow-Headers:
              type: string
      x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
        responses:
          default:
            statusCode: 200
            responseParameters:
              method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "'DELETE,GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,PATCH,POST,PUT'"
              method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "'Content-Type,Authorization,X-Amz-Date,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token'"
              method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "'https://example.com'"
        passthroughBehavior: when_no_match
        requestTemplates:
          application/json: "{\"statusCode\": 200}"
        type: mock
    get:
      summary: "Arrived at the root of the API"
      description: "Root API reached. This is for testing."
      produces:
      - application/json
      responses:
        200:
          description: 200 response
          schema:
            type: string
          headers:
            Access-Control-Allow-Origin:
              type: string
            Access-Control-Allow-Methods:
              type: string
            Access-Control-Allow-Headers:
              type: string
      x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
        responses:
          default:
            statusCode: 200
            responseParameters:
              method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "'DELETE,GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,PATCH,POST,PUT'"
              method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "'Content-Type,Authorization,X-Amz-Date,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token'"
              method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "'https://example.com'"
        passthroughBehavior: when_no_match
        requestTemplates:
          application/json: "{\"statusCode\": 200}"
        type: mock
x-amazon-apigateway-binary-media-types:
  - '*/*'
definitions:
  Empty:
    type: object
    title: Empty Schema
```

**index.js**

```
'use strict'
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    console.log('inside main routee');
    res.send('Hello to express world!');
    console.log('going out of main routee');
});

router.get('/friends', function (req, res) {
    console.log('inside friends routee');
  res.send({
        status: "success",
        data: [
            {"id": 3, "name": "Alex"},
            {"id": 4, "name": "TJ"}
        ]});
    console.log('going out of friends routee');
});

app.use('/', router);

// app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!'));

module.exports = app;
console.log('Exported server');
```

Comment: You need to create the actual Lamba function. In the tutorial you are referring to that file is called lamba.js

Comment: I saw a mention of `lambda.js` file in the guide that I was referring to. Which I've implemented as per the reference. Did you mean that file? Or is it something else?

Comment: Does anyone know the answer to this?

Comment: Go into Amazon Api Gateway resource and test the call inside AWS Console. It should provide more details about the error.